# Generate Random Password without these characters "l1o0"

Tags: php, security, random, passwords

I need to generate random password with condition:

- All characters are allowable except "**l1o0**"
- Length of 8 to 12 in characters

Codes I've tried:

```
function generateRandomPassword() {
  //Initialize the random password
  $password = '';

  //Initialize a random desired length
  $desired_length = rand(8, 12);

  for($length = 0; $length < $desired_length; $length++) {
    //Append a random ASCII character (including symbols)
    $password .= chr(rand(32, 126));
  }

  return $password;
}
```

How to avoid these 4 characters => "**l1o0**" ?

**Reason:**

- These 4 characters are sometimes confused the user.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please don't use any of the other answers currently provided for generating **passwords**. They're not secure by any measure.

- `rand()` -> No
- `mt_rand()` -> Definitely not

I'm going to pull this solution from a blog post aptly titled [*How to Securely Generate Random Strings and Integers in PHP*](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/07/how-safely-generate-random-strings-and-integers-in-php).

```
/**
 * Note: See https://paragonie.com/b/JvICXzh_jhLyt4y3 for an alternative implementation
 */
function random_string($length = 26, $alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz234567')
{
    if ($length < 1) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Length must be a positive integer');
    }
    $str = '';
    $alphamax = strlen($alphabet) - 1;
    if ($alphamax < 1) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Invalid alphabet');
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
        $str .= $alphabet[random_int(0, $alphamax)];
    }
    return $str;
}
```

Usage:

```
// Every ASCII alphanumeric except "loIO01":
$alphabet = 'abcdefghijkmnpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ23456789';
$string = random_string(12, $alphabet);
```

You probably don't have [`random_int()`](https://secure.php.net/random_int), unless you're reading this in the future when PHP 7 is released. For those of us living in the present, use [random_compat](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function generateRandomPassword($length = 8) {
    $characters = '23456789abcdefghjklmnpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomPassword = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomPassword .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomPassword;
}
```

Comment: still got `i` ... I need to avoid these 4 characters ... `l 1 o 0`

Comment: You could just remove it yourself :P anyways, updated :)

Comment: This isn't secure enough to use for passwords. `rand()` is particularly weak.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change your code . just use str_replace to replace those word's  You can try this solution :) . Just edited your code

```
function generateRandomPassword($length = 8) {
    $characters = '23456789abcdefghjklmnpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomPassword = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomPassword .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return str_replace(['l','1','o','0'], ['A','B','C','D'], $randomPassword);
}
```

Comment: Not only is this insecure (never use `rand()` to generate a password), it's also *biased* towards those 4 characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
$req_pword_len = 20;

$char_count = 0;
$password='';
$chars=str_split($string);
while ( $char_count < $req_pword_len ) {
    $char = mt_rand(0,61);
    $password .= (string) $chars[$char];
    $char_count++;
}
```

Change the value for

- $string to be just the characters you want to allow
- $req_pword_len to the required length of the password

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function generateRandomPassword($length = 8) {

    $randomPassword = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
      while (true) {
          //remove 0,1,I,O,l,o
          while(in_array(($number = rand(65, 122)), array(48, 49, 73, 79, 108, 111)));         
          if ($number <= 90 or $number >= 97) {
              $randomPassword .= chr($number);                                      
              break ;
           }
     }
  }
    return $randomPassword;
}

echo generateRandomPassword();
```